# How does denim insulation perform at low ambient temperatures?

Tags: insulation, windows, energy-efficiency, materials, winter

I am interested in how denim insulation like this performs at low ambient temperatures. Does anyone know? I am most interested in performance measures like R-value and what other factors affect this.

I have seen some estimates for other materials, such as [here](https://www.dupont.com/content/dam/dupont/amer/us/en/performance-building-solutions/public/documents/en/tech_solutions_538_understanding_polyiso_temps_43-d100866-enna.pdf) and [here](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/5524684/), but not for denim or for other "fabric-type" insulation.

(For me, "low temperatures" means 0 to 40 deg F, or -18 to 4 deg C. I am thinking about insulating windows at night with denim insulation and a vapor barrier, but I'm interested in a range of applications.)

Thanks!

Comment: Two layers of air tight Poly with an air gap would do better to reduce frost draft and avoid frost with a 1cm strip Lok for adhering Poly around frame. even 1 layer of sealed 4” air shield would work far better than thin denim to avoid the convection Rth loss

Comment: Will denim absorb moisture?

Comment: @Solar Mike I don't know, but I assume it wouldn't with a vapor barrier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this far better frost avoidance and cold draft reduction . good to -40’C

https://www.homerepairtutor.com/how-to-weatherize-windows-with-plastic-film-insulation/

I made insert frames and heat shrunk onto then remove and store in spring. But getting an air flow seal is best. They will inflate if not tight.  Easy to install with a hair dryer,  not too close .(6”)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a great idea! I have a deep window; could I set up multiple "layers" of bubble wrap adhering to the interior faces of my window frame? Would that have any effect?

Comment: Another question: Could I do a variant of this by using two layers of shrink film, adhering the bubble wrap to the interior side of the exterior layer?

Comment: And here's one more: Does the shrink film need to be hairdryer-ized to be effective? I ask because I have a window with an AC unit in it that my landlord will not let me remove, and it blocks the plane that the shrink film would occupy if fully shrunk.

Comment: Heatshrink film is most attractive  since it is transparent when stretched.  heat stretches it evenly.  Bubble wrap offers 2 layers, but if not air sealed air seal  leaks will spoil the insulation value of air R=1. A large roll of Poly. Is the cheapest solution with 1” duct tape on wood.

Comment: Thanks! When you say that a large roll of Poly. is the cheapest solution, you mean it's the cheapest solution to covering the AC? (and are you talking about something like this? https://www.lowes.com/pd/Dow-STYROFOAM-R-0-22-9-sq-ft-Unfaced-Polystyrene-Roll-Insulation-5-5-in-W-x-50-ft-L/50071521)

Comment: Looks good.  Seal with good tape

Comment: So once I have covered my AC with that stuff, would it make sense to use one or more layers of the bubble wrap and/or heat shrink film on the interior side of that?

Comment: As long as it is airtight